# How to use __str__ function to return a string representation of a class

Tags: python, class, external, txt

I have been tasked with creating an inventory manager in python, and one of the required is to define the following function within the class:

`__str__` - This function returns a string representation of a
class.

The class refers to a file (inventory.txt) which has the following format:
Country,Code,Product,Cost,Quantity

my code thus far is as follows:

```
# Creating the class:

class Shoes():

    # Constructor:
    def __init__(self,country,code,product,cost,quantity):
        self.country = country
        self.code = code
        self.product = product
        self.cost = cost
        self.quantity = quantity
    
    # Methods:
    def get_cost():

        inventory = open('inventory.txt','r')
        inventory_list = inventory.readlines()

        code = input("What is the code of the product:")

        for line in inventory_list:
            split_lines = line.split(",")
            if code == split_lines[1]:
                print("This product costs R{}".format(split_lines[3]))
                inventory.close()
    
    def get_quantity():
        inventory = open('inventory.txt','r')
        inventory_list = inventory.readlines()

        code = input("What is the code of the product:")

        for line in inventory_list:
            split_lines = line.split(",")
            if code == split_lines[1]:
                print("There are {} units in inventory".format(split_lines[4]))
                inventory.close()
    
    def __str__(self):
        pass
```

I haven't come across the **str** so I really am not sure how it works, and how to use it. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Make a normal string inside the function and return it.

Comment: Sorry not sure why str is going bold instead of showing the dashes...

Comment: @matszwecja So essentially it's just taking a line from the txt file and returning it as a string? (Sorry I thought it was a more complex function)

Comment: It should take its values from the object attributes (`self.country`, etc.), not text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.self.country},{self.self.code},{self.self.product}, {self.cost},{self.quantity })'
```

This way, when you assign values to a class, you can print its string representation

```
print(new_shoe)
```

More info here
[https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-oop/python-**str**/](https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-oop/python-__str__/)