# Getting the object memory location instead of the value itself

Tags: python, class, object

I'm writing a quiz game and getting a wierd result when trying to execute.
This is the main code:

```
question_bank = []
for question in question_data:
   question_text = question["text"]
   question_answer = question["answer"]
   new_question = Question(question_text, question_answer)
   question_bank.append(new_question)

quiz = QuizBrain(question_bank)

while quiz.still_has_questions():
   quiz.next_question()
```

and this is Class involved:

```
class QuizBrain:
   def __init__(self, q_list):
      self.question_number = 0
      self.question_list = q_list

   def still_has_questions(self):
      return self.question_number < len(self.question_list)

   def next_question(self):
      current_question = self.question_list[self.question_number]
      self.question_number += 1
      input(f"Q.{self.question_number}: **{current_question}** (True / False): ")
```

After running the code, I'm getting this line:

Q.1: **<question_model.Question object at 0x00000186F100FE80>** (True / False):

Don't know why the "current_question" returns the location and not the value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use \_\_str\_\_ function to return a string representation of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72350060/how-to-use-str-function-to-return-a-string-representation-of-a-class)

Comment: Do you have a `__str__` or `__repr__` function for your `Question` class? Here's a pretty good reference: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/python-str-repr-functions

Answer (score 0):

You should define `__str__` and/or `__repr__` function in your `Question` class.
For example:

```py
class Question:
    def __init__(self, question_text: str, question_answer: str):
        self.question_text = question_text
        self.question_answer = question_answer

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.question_text
    
    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f'Question({self.question_text=}, {self.question_answer=})'
```

```py
>>> q1 = Question('1 > 2 ?', 'False')
>>> print(q1) 
1 > 2 ?
>>> print(repr(q1))
Question(self.question_text='1 > 2 ?', self.question_answer='False')
```